# Lookup Filter on related list

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

I have 2 custom objects - Object A and Object B. 
Object A has a lookup to Account.
Object B has a lookup to Object A.

When creating an Object B record from Object A (related list), Object A is auto-populated (this is a standard functionality). When the user changes the Object A selected, the list is not filtered and is returning all Object A records in the org. The Object A records returned should be filtered so only the Object A associated in the Account are displayed.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this functionality? Preferably without coding. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the account association on Object B?

Comment: Based on what you asked, I think there is a relationship between Object B and Account which is not mentioned.

Comment: hi all. there is no relationship on Object B to Account